# How to create multiple new columns based on multiple conditional statements?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

[ First Stack question please be kind `:)` ]

I'm creating multiple new columns in a data frame based on multiple conditional statements of existing columns - all essentially new combinations of columns.

For example, if there are 4 columns (a:d), I need new columns of all combinations (abcd, abc, abd, etc) and a 0/1 coding based on threshold data in a:d.

Toy data example included and desired outcome. However needs to be scalable: there are 4 base columns, but I need all combinations of 2, 3 and 4 columns not just 3-value (abc, abd, .... ab, ac, ad, ... total n = 11)

[Background for context: this is actually flow cytometry data from multipotent stem cells that can grow into colonies of all lineage cell type (multipotent, or `abcd`) or progressively more restricted populations (only `abc`, or `abd`, `ab`, `ac`, etc)

```
# Toy data set
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(a = c(sample(10:50, 10)),
             b = c(sample(10:50, 10)),
             c = c(sample(10:50, 10)),
             d = c(sample(10:50, 10)))
```

Current code produces the desired result however, this needs 11 lines of repetitive code which is error prone and I hope has a more elegant solution:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    abcd = if_else(a > 30 & b > 20 & c > 30 & d > 30, 1, 0),
    abc = if_else(a > 30 & b > 20 & c > 30 & d <= 30, 1, 0),
    abd = if_else(a > 30 & b > 20 & c <= 30 & d > 30, 1, 0),
    acd = if_else(a > 30 & b <= 20 & c > 30 & d > 30, 1, 0),
    bcd = if_else(a <= 30 & b > 20 & c > 30 & d > 30, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Brent, what code are you using? Does this need to be extended to more columns or do you just need the array? Based on your requirements as described, this would be pretty use to build using an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Do you need the `ac` when `abc` is `1` ? Or you'd be ok with the 'most potent' type?

Comment: MrMoxy - written in R. Needs to be more robust than Excel as it's part of reproducible pipeline and scales up: yes will extend to more columns.

Comment: liborm - just the 'most potent' type. Although: if a, b & c all >threshold, then just 'abc'

Comment: @Brent please accept one of the answers if you consider your problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from your question, for each row you just need to find which columns meet the criteria defined in your `ifelse()` conditions.  This vectorized solution will add a column to your `df` which contains all the combinations.  This probably is also faster than multiple `ifelse` conditions as well.  Finally, the new column can be used for ordering or grouping.

```
# define the threshold levels for all columns
threshold = c(a=30, b=20, c=30, d=30)

# get names of columns meeting the threshold and paste names
df$combn <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  paste(names(x)[x > threshold], collapse = "")
})

> df
# A tibble: 10 x 5
       a     b     c     d combn
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
 1    21    49    46    49 bcd  
 2    41    28    37    46 abcd 
 3    25    36    34    36 bcd  
 4    43    31    47    40 abcd 
 5    44    13    48    10 ac   
 6    11    42    35    27 bc   
 7    28    18    29    48 d    
 8    40    11    30    17 a    
 9    46    20    19    20 a    
10    24    40    14    43 bd
```

Comment: Just a note - `sapply(1:nrow(df) ... ` does not look like it's using any vectorization - it's looping along the `df` row by row in R code.

Comment: Thank you nsinghs - this style of vectorised solution was my first thought too, however my group wants me to 'retrofit' it to some other existing code which relies on a binary 0/1 matrix. However I think I might be best using this vectorised solution, then modifying the downstream code - rather than making a complex intermediary binary table.

Comment: @liborm, `sapply` here is semi-vectorized in a sense that it is vectorized for whole row, but I see what you are saying.  That being said, `apply` is a better choice here and faster.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I get that correctly, you want to categorize each row into exactly one class, so getting the category name as concatenation of threshold tests should be enough. Then you can get `0/1` columns using `spread()`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    a_ = if_else(a > 30, 'a', 'x'),
    b_ = if_else(b > 20, 'b', 'x'),
    c_ = if_else(c > 30, 'c', 'x'),
    d_ = if_else(d > 30, 'd', 'x'),
    all_ = paste0(a_, b_, c_, d_),
    one_ = 1) %>% 
  spread(all_, one_, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-ends_with("_"))
```

Gives

```
# A tibble: 10 x 11
       a     b     c     d  abcd  axcx  axxx  xbcd  xbcx  xbxd  xxxd
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    11    42    35    27     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 2    21    49    46    49     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 3    24    40    14    43     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 4    25    36    34    36     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 5    28    18    29    48     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 6    40    11    30    17     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
 7    41    28    37    46     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 8    43    31    47    40     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 9    44    13    48    10     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
10    46    20    19    20     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

(You can use `''` instead of `'x'`, but then `spread()` will overwrite some of your original columns.)

Comment: Thank you liborm! That is an elegant `dplyr` solution and reproduces the binary table really well.